# Getting logged in user from IIS7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have enabled windows authentication and disabled rest of the authentications on my IIS 7.5. In my web application web.config I have set

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

When I try to get logged in user as `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` it's giving defaultappool as the user rather than the logged in windows user. This used to work correctly with IIS5.1 but not with IIS7.5. Is there anything else I should modify?

Comment: Check this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx. I'm not aware that something has changed for IIS 7.5 but take into account that the article is pretty old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user identity from the [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString() worked for me.